# Show that this matrix is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently working on quantum computing. 
In a literature source that I have, it is said that the following matrix $U$ is unitary. 
My question is, how can we show that in this matrix? I know that a matrix is unitary if:
$U^{*}U=I$

The matrix is an NxN matrix:

$U=\begin{pmatrix} -1+\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ...& \frac{2}{N} \\ 
\frac{2}{N} & -1+\frac{2}{N} & ...& \frac{2}{N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ...& -1+\frac{2}{N}  \end{pmatrix}  $

my first thought would be to pull the 1 out:

$U=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N} \\ 
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N}  \end{pmatrix}  - I $

Then you would have to show now that the matrix is unitary, but I can not get any further here.

I would be very happy if someone could help me to show that the matrix is unitary. I hope that my question is clear and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ U^{*} = U = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N} \\ 
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N}  \end{pmatrix}  - I $

(conjugate transpose is just transpose here, as conjugate of a real is the real number itself).

Let us take a new matrix $A$,
$ A= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N} \\ 
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ... & \frac{2}{N}  \end{pmatrix} $

So $U^{*}U= U^2 = (A-I)*(A-I) = A^2 - 2AI + I = A^2 - 2A + I$

$ A^2= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{4}{N} & \frac{4}{N} & ... & \frac{4}{N} \\ 
\frac{4}{N} & \frac{4}{N} & ... & \frac{4}{N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{4}{N} & \frac{4}{N} & ... & \frac{4}{N}  \end{pmatrix} = 2A $

So $A^2-2A$ is null matrix (all entries $0$)

And so $U^{*}U= I$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to reward you with an upvote, but I do not have enough reputation ... How did you come to the $4/N$ in the $A^2$ matrix? Can you explain that a little bit more in detail? My guess is that it's because you run the $((2/N)*(2/N))$ N times.

Comment: @QuantaMag Yes, exactly, I assume you can see how each entry of $A^2$ is obtained just by matrix multiplication, just like the way you described. $((2/N)*(2/N)) + ((2/N)*(2/N)) + ... $ (N times) = $ N*(4/N^2) =  4/N $. If there is still any confusion, I will edit my answer to clarify further. Also, if you found my answer satisfactorily answers your question, you can accept my answer, even if you do not have reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
U=\frac{2}{N}vv^T -I
$$ where $v=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T\in\Bbb R^N$. Hence $U=U^T$ and
$$
UU^T =U^2 =I-\frac{4}{N}vv^T +\frac{4}{N^2}(v^Tv)vv^T=I-\frac{4}{N}vv^T +\frac{4}{N}vv^T=I
$$ since $v^Tv = |v|^2=N$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm just trying to understand your answer. One more question, how did you come to this $v^Tv = |v|^2=N$ ?

Comment: @QuantaMag That is because $v^T v =v\cdot v = |v|^2=1^2+1^2+\cdots +1^2=N$ where $\cdot$ is standard inner(scalar) product, i.e. $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\cdots+ a_Nb_N$.